# How to ignore "handler": {}, "hibernateLazyInitializer": {} in json jackson in Spring hibernate project?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I am using fasterxml json with object mapper and below is my code:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

try {
   String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myClassObjectHere);
   return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonInString, HttpStatus.OK);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

The way I have implemented and am using the code, i get desired output but json has 2 random strange values in certain json objects as follows:

```json
{
   "listing": {
      "listingId": 1,
      "name": "Business",
      "handler": {},
      "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
   },
   "handler": {},
   "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
},
```

How to configure objectmappper to ignore `"handler": {}, "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}` values from outputted json ?

I tried solutions below:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

But its not working and the output is still the same as i posted above.
Also, I know I can ignore these handler and hibernateLazyInitializer in json by annotating classes with `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` but is there **any way to globally configure json jackson object mapper** so that it never adds these values in my outputted json?

Comment: Try using DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES Instead of objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Comment: which version of jackson are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.8.5 version

Comment: I get this error while using `DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`

 Feature cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: thats for below jackson 1.9 version since you are using 2.8.5 my sugeestion wont work

Comment: okay..any solution for 2.8.5 ?

Answer (score 17):

You could try adding a mixin to Object.class:

```
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, IgnoreHibernatePropertiesInJackson.class);
    return mapper;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
private abstract class IgnoreHibernatePropertiesInJackson{ }
```

Comment: What if we're not using Entity classes and its a plain POJO ?

Comment: it works! I don't know how or why but it works.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same problem and found a way to **globally** get hibernate entities mapped correctly by adding the Hibernate4Module to the mapper:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(
    new Hibernate4Module().configure(
        Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, true));
```

Comment: I already have this but its not working.
Below is my code:

`public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
  Hibernate5Module module = new Hibernate5Module();
  module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
  module.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
        registerModule(module);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `"handler": {}, "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}` properties seems to be empty or null. You can use the following configuration to ignore empty or null properties.

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

Or if you have access to the Class annotate `handler` and `hibernateLazyInitializer` with `@JsonIgnore` this will prevent it from being Serialized globally.

Comment: I have access to class but as I mentioned in my question, I dont wanna use that annotation on classes because I will have to do that on many of my classes and if missed one, it will be pain.

Comment: `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);`



Didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Annotation over the class `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` worked for me.

Comment: To prevent losing previously defined properties, use:
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) `
because ignoreUnknown's default value is [false](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()) and deleting it may cause different bugs