# No serializer found for class,no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Was testing my API to get a "Queue" by the ID and got the below error.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.ohramsbackend.model.Queue["patientQueue"]->com.example.ohramsbackend.model.Patient$HibernateProxy$dfNQ5Aj5["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.ohramsbackend.model.Queue["patientQueue"]->com.example.ohramsbackend.model.Patient$HibernateProxy$dfNQ5Aj5["hibernateLazyInitializer"])

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="queue")
public class Queue{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long queueId;
    
    @Column(name="requestTime")
    private LocalDateTime requestTime;
    
    @Column(name="acceptTime")
    private LocalDateTime acceptTime;
    
    @Column(name="completeTime")
    private LocalDateTime completeTime;
    
    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="icNumber")
    private Patient patientQueue;
}
```

May I know why I can't get the Queue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
You need to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` above the name of the class.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="queue")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Queue {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long queueId;

  ...
}
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353793/what-does-jsonignorepropertieshibernatelazyinitializer-handler-do) to have more detail