# No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.byte.ByteBuddyInterceptor (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jackson

I am trying to pull features of a product using hibernate API in Spring Boot application.

Feature.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "feature")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Feature extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "code", updatable = false)
    private String code;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;

        // getters & setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "code", updatable = false)
    private String code;

        // getters & setters
}
```

when i call below method in Rest Controller class

```
@GetMapping("/list/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Feature>> retrieveList(@PathVariable("productId") String productId) {
        List<Feature> featureList = featureService.retrieveListByProductId(productId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(featureList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Feature> retrieveListByProductId(String productId) {
        return featureRepo.retrieveListByProductId(productId);
    }

@Override
    public List<Feature> retrieveListByProductId(String productId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String queryString = "from Feature f where f.product.id = :productId order by f.name";
        Query<Feature> query = session.createQuery(queryString, Feature.class);
        query.setParameter("productId", productId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

i am getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.cm.entity.Feature["product"]->com.cm.entity.Product$HibernateProxy$HyMnl1iV["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:46)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I added below property in Spring Boot(2.7.5)
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
in application.properties file. But still, it is throwing an exception.

I also tried by changing from FetchType.LAZY to FetchType.EAGER. Though it is working, i want to load product lazyly.

I tried the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353793/what-does-jsonignorepropertieshibernatelazyinitializer-handler-do). Still getting the same error

Can someone help me to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656517/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-bytebuddy-bytebuddyinterc)

Comment: birca! thanks for quick reply. i am using hibernate