# No serializer found for class Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i am creating a spring boot crud application while running the project i got the error was i attached below.

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.project.TodoApp.entity.Employee$HibernateProxy$1NCHjs6v["hibernateLazyInitializer"]) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1308) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3] at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:30) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]`

what i tried so far i attached below please check it.

**EmployeeController**

```
@PutMapping(path = "/update")
    public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeUpdateDTO employeeUpdateDTO)
    {
        return employeeService.updateEmployees(employeeUpdateDTO);
    }
```

**EmployeeService**

```
public interface EmployeeService {


    Employee updateEmployees(EmployeeUpdateDTO employeeUpdateDTO);
}
```

**EmployeeServiceIMPL**

```
public Employee updateEmployees(EmployeeUpdateDTO employeeUpdateDTO) {

        if(employeeRepo.existsById(employeeUpdateDTO.getEmployeeid()))
        {
            Employee employee = employeeRepo.getById(employeeUpdateDTO.getEmployeeid());
            employee.setEmployeename(employeeUpdateDTO.getEmployeename());
            employee.setAddress(employeeUpdateDTO.getAddress());
            employee.setMobile(employeeUpdateDTO.getMobile());
            employee.setActivestate(employeeUpdateDTO.isActivestate());

            employeeRepo.save(employee);
            return employee;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Employee ID Not Found");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**EmployeeUpdateDTO**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class EmployeeUpdateDTO {

    private Long employeeid;
    private String employeename;
    private String address;
    private int mobile;
    private boolean activestate;

}
```

here is the pom.xml file i attached below. i listed what are the dependencies added

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please share your pom.xml or whatever you are using for dependencies? Also please include your java version.

Comment: java version 17

Comment: i attached the pox.xml file

Comment: Can you please also share your Employee class implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to jackson serialization with a JPA Entity, for reasons explained here: [What does @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353793/what-does-jsonignorepropertieshibernatelazyinitializer-handler-do)

Use this annotation on your Employee class:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Alternatively you can set this property as suggested by exception:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

NOTE: this property will affect all serialization in your application

Hope this will help :D